# DIY attaching an EU power plug to an US charger?

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, power-electronics, conversion, plug

I've received some Chinese walkie talkies today, which annoyingly enough had the charging adapters to the charging stations come with US plugs instead of EU plugs.

The adapters are marked with

```
INPUT: 100-240V ~ 50/60hz 0.3A
OUTPUT: 10V (DC symbol) 500mA
```

In my country (Norway) the outlets have cirka **230V AC at 50Hz** *(I'm 99.8% sure)*.

What would I need to be able to relatively safely be able to plug them into Norwegian mains?

Albeit, as temporarily ***less safe***, (since I'm unable to get powerplug adapters at the moment), would something start to smoke if I were to carefully solder and heatshrink on some lamp plug-leads that I've got laying around the house, onto the power adapter's US pins?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: You have 230 V phase-phase in Norway. No issue in plug modding it.

Comment: @winny Yeah i thought as much, but never hurts to get some second opinion :)  Would you mind writing it as answer so that i could accept it as [solved]?

Comment: If your plug has 2 conductors, its single phase not 3 phase.

Comment: @MIL-SPEC oh ok. I was simply going by what it said on https://snl.no/vekselstr%C3%B8m
"In Norway and many other countries (including most countries in Europe), three-phase alternating current (see Figure 3) with a frequency of 50 hertz is used in the public distribution network. The voltage in the local grid in Norway has an effective value of about 230 volts." [google translated]

Comment: Could you post a picture of the chargers and cables?  There might be a better way to fix things.

Comment: @DhP Don't solder. Can you cut it off and screw on a Schuko-plug instead?

Comment: @MIL-SPEC Norway is one of the few European countries to use 230 V phase-phase instead of 230 V phase-neutral.

Comment: @JRE Done. Sorry for the crappy lighting and quality though.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvgzT.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKYKj.jpg

Comment: @winny I'm not sure what Schuko plugs are. But if's the pins that actually get stuck into the wall outlet, unfortunately the spacing between the original US pins and even the plastic surface they've been given to protrude out from, is too narrow to drill out round holes for euro pins (i think). :/

Comment: Oh! There is no cable. Just a wall wart. Then it’s adapter for you. Schuko is the European docket standard for most countries, Norway included.

Comment: There's cable now though.. :d https://imgur.com/a/xssLdoK .. And no magic smoke, funny odors or spasms when touching it. It's says 11V and not 10V output though, but that's probably just my multimeter being ultra shitty. Charger seems to be working ok, either way.

Comment: @winny The instructions said to charge the battery for 5 hours before turning on the walkie. But i'm thinking it'll do worky quite nice, since nothing popped when it got plugged in, and the LED's on both adapter and station seem to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You could buy a US to Norway AC plug adapter. These are a few euros/dollars online, and are often used by Americans visiting Europe.

Edit: I mean a passive adapter that reconnects the pins without changing the voltage.

Comment: Those are strictly adapters? With no other internals other than going from lead-to-lead? (see my second question above)

Comment: @DhP If you really want to heat shrink something, I would grab another DC adapter and adapt the low voltage side. Otherwise, just get a real adapter, much safer and less risk you damage something.

Comment: Other than myself, what could be damaged do you think?